# Bootstrap Woes. Resizing Google Maps

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm having all sorts of problems re sizing my Google Maps using Twitter's Bootstrap. As it stands right now I have a gigantic white outline and my nav bar is covering the area to the left of it. I'm tried all sorts of wizardry to get it to full screen without cutting off some controls but my attempts have been fruitless. There is some inline Javascript that I tried to use to achieve this but it did not seem to do the trick.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Project</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDd8Vlwh0ukzT-3zKSnlUqqZOqxnQ9_0fE">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Location Information</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img class="img-responsive logoWiki" src="img/wiki_logo.png" />
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: articleList" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: content"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Neighborhood Map <img src="img/map_icon.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="mailto:iam@jamesiv.es">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <ul data-bind="foreach: pins">
                    <li data-bind="text: name">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var h = $(window).height(),
                offsetTop = 60; // Calculate the top offset

            $('#map-canvas').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
        }).resize();
    </script>

</body>
</html>



#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

.priority {
    z-index: 999;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Working example: http://jamesiv.es/projects/map

Comment: please include your relevant CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the main post with the sidebar.css information. The other styles are inline or inherited from Bootstrap. The relevent javascript is inline also. Also uploaded a working example here: http://jamesiv.es/projects/map

Answer (score 0):

Your working example gives 404 when clicked.

Try inserting this piece of code which triggers the "resize" function when the sidebar is drawn completely.

```
$('#sidebar-wrapper').on('shown', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```